# Domain independent server configuration

Tags: jakarta-ee, glassfish, websphere, weblogic, application-server

Is there a way to specify domain independent server configuration (or deployment descriptors) for Weblogic, Glassfish and WAS servers? I need something similar to Jboss's `standalone.xml`

Update: I understand each application server has its own config files, so I'm looking for three config files, one each for Weblogic, Glassfish and WAS. Only requirement is that the config file has to be domain independent (i.e. configuration file shouldn't be part of the deployed application)

Answer (score 0):

It depends on specifically what descripters you need- many of the Application Servers have custom named xml files, for example weblogic.xml/weblogic-application.xml. Those can be placed alongside the equivalent files for say JBoss which uses jboss-web.xml.

Of course some aren't simple to just replace, such as the contents of web.xml. Perhaps not what you are after, but you can build the application WAR/EAR/JAR using something like Ant, and specific what web.xml file to use. If you automate the process you could create a jar file for each server type on each build.

web.xml itself can only be defined once per war file, though if you are using Servlet 3.0 I believe you can use web xml fragment files to define any listeners ([source](http://blogs.oracle.com/swchan/entry/servlet_3_0_web_fragment)).

Comment: Thanks for the reply! But all the files that you mentioned here: weblogic.xml, weblogic-application.xml & web.xml are all are domain dependent. I wanted a configuration file that is common for the application server and independent of various applications deployed on it.